# Prevent triggering an upload button with VueJS keyup.enter event

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

In VueJS, I am trying to use variations of `@keyup.enter` to prevent triggering an upload button that I have on the same page when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  I have tried:  `@keyup.enter.prevent`, `@keypress.enter.prevent`, `@keydown.enter.prevent` and `@click.prevent`.

The only one that catches the event is `@click.prevent` but that prevents me from using the upload button.

I'm using `ElementUI` for the upload.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Place your code to a sandbox and show us your issue there

Comment: First thing on mind is the `@keypress.enter.stop` alternation, as you need to stop this going through all nodes (including form or however you're uploading the file). But for sure it depends on the situation ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone! Just found out a simple solution. I'm using button tag for uploading images and changed it to anchor tag instead, not sure why it's hitting unnecessary event using button. Works like a charm!